# Add style from external scss file to SVG.js element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, svg.js

I create a svg and add a path to it with SVG.js as follow.

```
this.roomPlan = SVG('roomPlan').attr('id','roomPlanSvg').size(1024, 
768);
this.roomPlan.path(room.area.d);
```

I have a external `.scss` file and I have some style as follow;

```
.room-bg {
  fill: nb-theme(card-bg);
  stroke: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}
```

I want to add `.room-bg` selector to my path element as class like other html.
for example ;

```
<path class="room-bg" />
```

Note: I'm developing **Angular2-Typescript** app and I add `SVG.js` to project as npm package.

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do:

```
this.roomPlan.path(room.area.d).addClass("room-bg");
```

See: [http://svgjs.dev/manipulating/#addclass]

Comment: I try this but didnt.My styles are in scss file.

Comment: İf I put my style to .css file addClass method work properly but my style must be in scss file addClass method isnt working with scss file.

Comment: scss files typically get compiled to css when you build your app.  Browsers don't use scss files.

Comment: How can I use scss styles

Comment: Read the sass documentation to find out how to work with scss files.